# C++ templates with interface objects

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have the following code that doesn't compile.

```
class Base {
    public:
        virtual ~Base() { };
};

class Derived : public Base { };

class NotDerived { };

template <typename T>
class Group { };

int main() {
    Group<Base> *g = NULL;

    g = new Group<Base>();       // Works
    g = new Group<Derived>();    // Error, but I want it to work

    g = new Group<NotDerived>(); // Error, as expected
}
```

I understand that this won't compile because `g` is a different type than `Group<Derived>`.  To make this work in Java I would do something such as `Group<? extends Base> g`, but C++ doesn't have that keyword as far as I know.  What can be done?

Edit: I would like to clarify that I do not want it possible to set types not derived from `Base` as `g`.  I have updated my example to explain this.

Edit 2: There are two solutions to my problem.  [Dave's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184183/c-templates-with-interface-objects/7184569#7184569) I found to be simple and easy to define.  But [Bowie's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184183/c-templates-with-interface-objects/7184300#7184300) (along with [Mark's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184183/c-templates-with-interface-objects/7184568#7184568) additions) suited my needs better.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how this sort of thing works in Java. What are you trying to say with that syntax?

Comment: This wouldn't work in Java either. The syntax of `<? extends ...>` is not for supporting covariance, but is there to add a constraint on what types the generic may use.

Comment: See [C++ template polymorphism](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203388/c-templates-polymorphism)

Comment: Nicol: It's so that I can have a type of factory class that returns a certain type of interface.

Mark: it certainly does work in Java.

Praetorian: That appears to be exactly my problem, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make Group< Base > a base class of all Group< T > T != Base.

```
class Base {
    public:
        virtual ~Base() { };
};

class Derived : public Base { };


template <typename T> class Group;

struct Empty { };

template <typename T>
struct base_for_group_t {
    typedef Group<Base> type;
};

template <>
struct base_for_group_t<Base> {
    typedef Empty type;
};

template <typename T>
class Group : public base_for_group_t<T>::type { };

int main() {
    Group<Base> *g = 0;

    g = new Group<Base>();    // Works
    g = new Group<Derived>(); //  now works
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately now something like this is legal: `class NotDerived {}; g = new Group<NotDerived>();`.  I would like to maintain type safety if possible.

Answer (score 5):

The classes `Group<Base>` and `Group<Derived>` are entirely unrelated, different classes. Pointers to them are not convertible in either direction.

If you need runtime-polymorphic behaviour, your class template `Group` could derive from a common (non-templated) base class:

```
class Group // base
{
   virtual ~Group() { }
};

template <typename T>
class ConcreteGroup : public Group
{
  // ...
  T * m_impl;
};

Group * g1 = new ConcreteGroup<A>;
Group * g1 = new ConcreteGroup<B>;
```

Comment: ConcreteGroup does not need to inherit Group?

Answer (score 2):

[Bowie Owens's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184183/c-templates-with-interface-objects/7184300#7184300) handles the covariance you need to solve the original question. As for the constraint you asked for in the edited question - you can achieve this by using type traits.

```
template <typename T, class Enable = void> class Group;

template <typename T>
class Group<T, typename enable_if<is_base_of<Base, T>::value>::type> 
    : public base_for_group_t<T>::type { };
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot get it to compile on my end (I am unfamiliar with how to correctly use type traits).  Can you provide a more complete example? (I assumed `Group<T, typename ...>` is supposed to be `template<typename T, typename enable_if...> class Group`, however that didn't work.

Comment: Try again with the `::value` on is_base_of. (Difference required between `boost::enable_if` and `std::enable_if`). If not, what's the error you get?

Comment: Ah, I did not include the std namespace.  Your original code works as expected. ;)

Comment: You should accept Bowie's answer rather than mine, he done the clever work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think C++ support that. C++ Template is handled completely at compile time so it doesn't support **polymorphism**. That means the type of the template arguments should be exactly the same for both side of the assignment expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're going for.  I'm not sure it's the best approach (and you might want to look at [Boost.Factory](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/functional/factory/doc/html/index.html)).

```
template <class T>
class Factory {

public:
  virtual T* operator()() = 0;
};

template <class Derived, class Base>
class ConcreteFactory : public Factory<Base> {

public:
  virtual Base* operator()() {
    return new Derived();
  }
};

class Base {
public:
  virtual ~Base() {};
};

class Derived1 : public Base { };
class Derived2: public Base {};

class NotDerived {};

int main()
{
  Factory<Base>* g;

  g = new ConcreteFactory<Derived1, Base>;
  g = new ConcreteFactory<Derived2, Base>;
  //  g = new ConcreteFactory<NotDerived, Base>; // Will not work if you try to do this
}
```

Comment: This appears to be the most type-safe solution so far.  The definition of both Derived1 and Base is a bit redundant, but it's nothing that I wont know already (and I can avoid with a typedef).  Thanks, :)