# Template Parameter Inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism

I haven't written C++ in a while, so I'm a bit rusty. If I have a class like this:

```
class JsonType{
    protected:
        map<string, JsonType>* objects;
}
```

and a class that inherits from that:

```
class JsonObject : public JsonType{
    public:
        JsonObject(){
            this->objects = new map<string, JsonObject>();
        }
}
```

why would I be getting a compiler error `cannot convert...JsonObject...to...JsonType`? Shouldn't that be legal, since JsonObject is a JsonType?

Comment: Converting `A` to `B` is very different from converting `X<A>` to `X<B>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Templates polymorphism](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203388/c-templates-polymorphism)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add JsonObject objects to the map, but the types do not match for initialization.

Edit: You have to initialize it as:

```
this->objects = new map<string, JsonType>();
```

But if you have either objects:

```
JsonType js = new JsonType();
```

or

```
JsonObject js2 = new JsonObject();
```

or

```
JsonType js3 = new JsonObject();
```

You can add any of these objects to the map initialized as above.

Answer (score 1):

`objects` doesn't use `JsonObject` for its `value_type`, it uses `JsonType`s.

In other words you are allocating the wrong kind of `map` to store into `objects`.