# C++ Template Covariance

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, covariance

Can you use the covariance propriety for the generic types (through the templates) in C++?

I already found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203388/c-templates-polymorphism) that answers my question, but I ask it again since it has already been two years! In addiction, though it is explained that there can be no covariance in C++ in templates, there is no explanation about that!

Can you help me about news/explanation of this topic?

Comment: You should add a code sample for what you call "template covariance" : the answer of the linked question still apply

Comment: If some purported construction isn't part of the language, how much "explanation" would satisfy you regarding its absence from the language? Isn't "it doesn't exist" enough?

Comment: "In addiction..." typo, or just can't get enough coding? Hmmm...

Comment: Actually, what you asks about in the linked question is named "contravariance", not "covariance"

Comment: There's so need to explain addiction.

Comment: @kerrek The C++ language is well-known for trying hard to encompass a lot of paradigms, so "it doesn't exists" is totally unsatisfying in this land.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the reference to an earlier question as a clarification device, it seems you are asking why `T<Derived>` is not usually derived from `T<Base>`.

Consider `T` = `std::shared_ptr`.

You don't want to be able to do this:

```
void foo( shared_ptr<Base>& p ) { p.reset( new Derived2 ); }

auto main() -> int
{
    shared_ptr<Derived1> p;
    foo( p );   // Oops, p now points to unrelated Derived2
}
```