# Converting std::function<void(Derived*)> to std::function<void(Base*)>

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

First, I define two classes, which inherits from one another.

```
class A {
};
class B : public A {
};
```

Then, I declare a function that uses an `std::function<void(A*)>` :

`void useCallback(std::function<void(A*)> myCallback);`

Finally, I receive a `std::function` of a different (but theoretically compatible) type from somewhere else that I would like to use in my callback function:

```
std::function<void(B*)> thisIsAGivenFunction;

useCallback(thisIsAGivenFunction);
```

My compiler (clang++) refuses this because the type of `thisIsAGivenFunction` doesn't match the expected type. But with `B` inheriting from `A`, it would make sense for `thisIsAGivenFunction` to be acceptable.

Should it be? If not, why? And if it should, then what am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Templates polymorphism](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203388/c-templates-polymorphism)

Comment: it is not duplicate, `std::function` supports such *conversions*. but in the other way, you can convert `std::function<void(A*)>` to `std::function<void(B*)>`, because function that operates on `A*` can do the same when it receives an instance of `B*`, but not the other way

Comment: The source of your problem is using `std::function` as a callback instead of accepting a `Functor` as a template argument. Unless you have a good reason to do this, don't do it.

Comment: What does your callback pass to your `std::function`?  What if it passes a pointer to `class C:public A{}` to it, what does `thisIsAGivenFunction` do then?  Please answer both questions, neither are rhetorical.

Answer (score 18):

Let's suppose that your class hierarchy is a little bigger:

```
struct A { int a; };
struct B : A { int b; };
struct C : A { int c; };
```

and you have functions like below:

```
void takeA(A* ptr)
{
    ptr->a = 1;
}

void takeB(B* ptr)
{
    ptr->b = 2;
}
```

Having that, we can say that `takeA` is *callable* with any instance of class derived from `A` (or `A` itself), and that `takeB` is *callable* with any instance of class `B`:

```
takeA(new A);
takeA(new B);
takeA(new C);

takeB(new B);
// takeB(new A); // error! can't convert from A* to B*
// takeB(new C); // error! can't convert from C* to B*
```

Now, what `std::function` is, it is a *wrapper for callable* objects. It doesn't care much about the signature of stored function object **as long as** that object is *callable* with parameters of its `std::function` wrapper:

```
std::function<void(A*)> a; // can store anything that is callable with A*
std::function<void(B*)> b; // can store anything that is callable with B*
```

What you are trying to do, is to convert `std::function<void(B*)>` to `std::function<void(A*)>`. In other words, you want to store callable object taking `B*` within wrapper class for functions taking `A*`. Is there an implicit conversion of `A*` to `B*`? No, there is not.

That is, one can as well call `std::function<void(A*)>` with a pointer to an instance of class `C`:

```
std::function<void(A*)> a = &takeA;
a(new C); // valid! C* is forwarded to takeA, takeA is callable with C*
```

If `std::function<void(A*)>` could *wrap* an instance of callable object taking only `B*`, how would you expect it to work with `C*`?:

```
std::function<void(B*)> b = &takeB;
std::function<void(A*)> a = b;
a(new C); // ooops, takeB tries to access ptr->b field, that C class doesn't have!
```

Fortunately, the above code does not compile.

However, doing this the opposite way is fine:

```
std::function<void(A*)> a = &takeA;
std::function<void(B*)> b = a;
b(new B); // ok, interface is narrowed to B*, but takeA is still callable with B*
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass `&Foo(Apple)` when somebody may pass you a random `Fruit` including a `Pear`.

Comment: I don't get it. In my case my function `useCallback` expects a random `Fruit`, and when I'm passing it a `Pear` the compiler complains.

Comment: @Ecco. I think this is that your `useCallback` expects to call a function with a `Fruit` (could be `Pear` or `Apple`) and you are giving it a function that expects at least a `Pear`.

Comment: Niall is right. `useCallback` may give your `thisIsAGivenFunction` an `A*` pointer to a `C` object. Your function has to accept **all** `A` objects, not a subset.

Answer (score 2):

It works but in opposite direction:

```
struct A {};
struct B: A {};

struct X {};
struct Y: X {};

static X useCallback(std::function<X(B)> callback) {
    return callback({});
}

static Y cb(A) {
    return {};
}

int main() {
    useCallback(cb);
}
```

The signature of callback declares what will be passed to it and what is to be got back. Specific callback can take less specific types if doesn't care too much about them. Similarly it can return more specific type, extra information will be stripped. Refer to covariant vs contravariant types (input/output in simplified wording).

Comment: Right. See contravariance in std::function  http://cpptruths.blogspot.com/2015/11/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c.html#function_contravariance