# Qt - C2664 - cannot convert parameter 1 from 'QList<T>' to 'QList<T> &'

Tags: c++, qt

Using Qt 5.4 and compiling in Qt Creator.

In widget 1, there is a file-scoped QList:

```
static QList< Tag * > g_Tags;
```

Note that Tag inherits from BaseDataObject. Both Tag and BaseDataObject have private, undefined copy constructors and operator=() functions.

Also in widget 1, there is the following constructor call:

```
MoverDialog dlg( g_Tags, this );
```

In simplified form, MoverDialog.h looks like:

```
class MoverDialog : public QDialog
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Constructors/Destructor

    explicit MoverDialog(   QList< BaseDataObject * > & availableList,
                            QWidget * parent = 0 );
    virtual ~MoverDialog();

etc. etc.
```

When I compile this code, I get the following error:

```
D:\MyDocs\Projects\dsb\Src\Apps\RecipeMgr_Qt\Source\Ui\RecipeGeneralWidget.cpp:166: error: C2664: 
'MoverDialog::MoverDialog(QList<T> &,QList<T> &,QWidget *)' : cannot convert parameter 1 
from 'QList<T>' to 'QList<T> &'
with
[
    T=recipemgr::BaseDataObject *
]
and
[
    T=recipemgr::Tag *
]
and
[
    T=recipemgr::BaseDataObject *
]]
```

Compilation succeeds if I change the declaration of the file-scoped list to:

```
static QList< BaseDataObject * > g_Tags;
```

Why does compilation fail with the file-scoped list declared using "Tag *" like shown at the top of this posting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Templates polymorphism](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203388/c-templates-polymorphism)

Comment: I read the polymorphism link and that did explain the overall issue. However, the error message states that it can't convert the "QList<T>" to a "QList<T> &". Ignorning the lack of template polymorphism, I would think that my list is being passed by reference as written. So why did the template polymorphism issue cause that specific error message?